# Paypal start up testing and managing payment

Tags: paypal

I am new to Paypal integration to websites. I just created a sand box test account to try and create buttons.

I am trying to make use of Paypal subscription to my website.

Can anyone give some basic information of how can I test and increase my knowledge on Paypal integration to my website.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are going in the right direction.  You would want to sign up for a developer account at developer.paypal.com.  Once you have your developer account set up, then you would want to log in and create a test sandbox buyer and sandbox account.  You can use these accounts to create test subscription buttons and walk through and sign up for the subscription with your buyer account.  This will allow you to test with subscriptions in the sandbox.